# Is there any HTML 5 "Builder"

Tags: html, ide

Or do you know of anyone working on one? I've been checking all the stuff you can do with HTML 5 [here](http://www.phpguru.org/html5-examples#html5.canvas.examples) and some other sites and is amazing. I think such a big library should have some IDE with intellisense and easy documentation (like when you press F1 on Visual Studio while a symbol is highlighted) and all that stuff. And if there is not then I should probably start working on one :).

Comment: Recently Embarcadero (makers of lots of other something-builder named products) have announced an HTML5Builder product. Functionally it's a web dev tool similar to their RadPHP and C++Builder products, from what I gather though I have not seen it yet and it's not yet released. I gather the release date is September 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of known IDEs and their latest version, like [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/), [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/), support natively HTML5. You can find [more info](http://www.html5trends.com/best-of/6-html5-authoring-tools/) and pick one according to your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous HTML 5 IDEs, it's important to not necessarily separate current web technologies with HTML5 as they are really are very close to being one and the same. For example, the latest version of Adobe's tool offer support for HTML5, as well as other IDEs such as Aptana. Unfortunately, the HTML5 spec is not done yet so there will be discrepancies between browsers, which a builder could work around, but will put a lot of onus on you.

Alternatively, there are numerous client and server-side frameworks that abstract HTML5 and some of its features, each of these have varying levels of support, a builder, and intellisense. For example, I'm a co-founder of the NOLOH development platform (http://www.noloh.com), which abstracts away browser differences and supports HTML5 transparently to you the developer, allowing you to concentrate on your application and functionality without worrying about the plumbing. We also have what's known as "code stubs" that you can add to any IDE most IDEs and get intellisense/auto-complete functionality. We also have a visual builder in the works that should be out relatively soon.

Whatever you pick, just make sure you're comfortable with it, but you definitely don't want to re-invent the wheel here.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely try [HTML5 Builder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/html5-builder).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://paulirish.com/2010/announcing-html5-boilerplate/)

Comment: Boilerplate is just a template to get things started with a new html 5 project, the question was referring to the ide to implement the project but its a great way to get things started in the correct way.

Comment: No it is asking for a "Builder" and mentions IDE's in passing. If you download the lated version of the Boilerplate you find that tools and scripts are being added that build various components and extend them. An IDE is a set of tools to manipulate a particular area and may contain "Builders" but arguably is not in itself a builder.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for something that builds mobile sites or ads html5 builder, maybe you could try http://mobdis.com.